# Перераспределение данных в массиве в Excel

Tags: массивы, excel, макрос

Скажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли выполнить такую операцию:
Имеем много столбцов с разным количеством ячеек, например

```
> 9000102       9000103   9000105   
> 67879          45271      35463    
> 67583          34215             
>                 23452
```

Можно ли автоматизировать формулой или макросом приведение этой таблицы к виду

```
> 9000102    67879 
> 9000102    67583 
> 9000103    45271 
> 9000103    34215
> 9000103    23452 
> 9000105    35463
```

Перепробывал кучу вариантов со сложным условием ЕСЛИ и тп - ничего не помогает(((

Comment: Уточните расположение данных и результат. Похоже, сообщение неправильно отформатировано

Comment: Теперь более удобочитаемо

Comment: Что значит много столбцов разной длины? Внутри них написана длина чего-то? Или это сама длина столбцов? Если это длина столбцов то в каких единицах измерения ячейках/пикселях? В любом случае вам нужен какой-то из алгоритмов сортировки. Я подозреваю что речь идет о втором варианте, поэтому вам придется писать VBA макрос реализующий алгоритм сортировки плюс доступ к длине ячеек.
P.S. Может речь идет о длине строки внутри ячейки? Я ничего не могу понять из ваших записей.

Comment: Количество ячеек в каждом столбе разное

Comment: Понял. В общем вам нужен макрос который считает количество непустых ячеек в каждом столбце который есть у вас в таблице, затем отдельно сортирует длинные(7 значные) столбцы и короткие столбцы(5 значные) в зависимости от количества непустых ячеек в них. При этом большие столбцы сортируются по убыванию, а маленькие по возрастанию. Могу только сказать что это проще написать на VBA чем писать сложную формулу через убогую встроенную консоль. Удачи.

Comment: Идею понял, спасибо. Но боюсь, что с ходу я это не реализую) Будем думать

Comment: Скорее всего это кто-то уже сделал до Вас. Попробуйте сначала погуглить словосочетания вроде "column sorting excel vba"

Comment: Я бывает на русскоязычных форумах не понимаю, что отвечают)) а вы говорите, про зарубежные

Comment: Ну Excel это же американская программа, поэтому имеет смысл читать первоисточники если хотите сэкономить время, к тому же грамматика VBA написана на английском. Информация на русских форумах по программированию за редким исключением просто копипаст откуда то из-за рубежа.

Answer (score 1):

> jmu: врядли найдетется много знатоков
> VBA.

Не считал, но есть немало :)

Даже с небольшими знаниями VBA процедуру для решения данной задачи можно нарисовать.

В коде:

"*list_data*" - лист с данными

"*list_result*" - лист для вывода результата

Код разместить в общем модуле книги.

```
Sub TransposeRange()
Dim ArrData
Dim ArrResult
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    With Worksheets("list_data")
        ArrData = .UsedRange ' данные в массив
        i = .UsedRange.Count ' количество ячеек в используемой области листа
    End With

    ReDim ArrResult(1 To i, 1 To 2) ' задать размерность диапазона

    For j = 1 To UBound(ArrData, 2) ' цикл по 2 размерности (столбцы диапазона)
        For i = 2 To UBound(ArrData, 1) ' цикл по 1 размерности (строки диапазона)
            ' если есть значение, то запись в результирующий массив
            If ArrData(i, j) <> "" Then
                k = k + 1
                ArrResult(k, 1) = ArrData(1, j)
                ArrResult(k, 2) = ArrData(i, j)
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

    ' выгрузка массива на другой лист
    With Worksheets("list_result")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(k, 2) = ArrResult
    End With

    MsgBox "Всего записей - " & k
End Sub
```

Если в столбцах нет пустых ячеек между заполненными (неразрывные диапазоны данных), выполнение кода можно ускорить, добавив выход из внутреннего цикла. Весь цикл будет выглядеть так:

...................

```
    For j = 1 To UBound(ArrData, 2) ' цикл по 2 размерности (столбцы диапазона)
        For i = 2 To UBound(ArrData, 1) ' цикл по 1 размерности (строки диапазона)
            If ArrData(i, j) <> "" Then
                ' если есть значение, то запись в результирующий массив
                k = k + 1
                ArrResult(k, 1) = ArrData(1, j)
                ArrResult(k, 2) = ArrData(i, j)
            Else
                ' если нет значения, то выход из внутреннего цикла
                GoTo ExitFor_i
            End If
        Next i
ExitFor_i:
    Next j
```

...................

Answer (score 0):

> igumnov: 
> Могу только сказать что это
> проще написать на VBA чем писать
> сложную формулу через убогую
> встроенную консоль

Кому как :)

Пример. Исходные данные автора в *A1:C4*

Вспомогательная строка:

```
A6=0

B6: =СЧЁТ($A$2:A4)+1

C6: =СЧЁТ($A$2:B4)+1
```

Первый столбец результата (заголовки таблицы):

```
A8: =ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(1:1)>СЧЁТ($A$2:$C$4);"";ИНДЕКС($A$1:$C$1;ПОИСКПОЗ(СТРОКА(1:1);$A$6:$C$6;1)))
```

Второй столбец результата (данные):

```
B8: =ЕСЛИ(A8="";"";ГПР(A8;$A$1:$C$4;СЧЁТЕСЛИ($A$8:A8;A8)+1;))
```

Работает. Но на больших объемах лучше макросом.